# socket.send() doesn't work on Opera 11.10

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, socket.io

I'm using **socket.io** with Opera 11.10.

I have seen that socket.send() doesn't work on Opera 11.10.

ON socket.io website I have seen that only Opera 10.61 is supported.

it's strange because the connection went good, and  on 'message' event is fired without problem... the problem is only to send messages.

Could I do something to use socket.io with this version or do I have to wait new socket.io update?

Thank you!

Comment: I have seen the same issue with Nowjs (which use Socket.io under the covers). That being said, this is not really a question answerable on StackOverflow, you should file a bug with Socket.io instead.

Answer (score 0):

Which transport is this? I myself have seen an issue with xhr/jsonp polling.  However with 11.00 and 10.61 both websockets (when enabled) and flashsockets work fine for me.